# VBA error: Object doesn't support this action (Error 445)

Tags: vba, ms-word

Whenever I start Microsoft Word and use the following macro for the first time I get the error:

> Object doesn't support this action (Error 445)

If I relaunch the makro the error disapppears.

```
Sub SelectedURLtoHyperlink()

    Dim MyData As DataObject
    Dim strClip As String

    Set MyData = New DataObject
    Selection.Copy
    MyData.GetFromClipboard
    strClip = MyData.GetText

    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=strClip, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Selection.Range 

End sub
```

Apparently the error is in the line `Set MyData = New DataObject`.

Does anybody have an idea why this error appears?

Comment: That line wouldn't throw that [error message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-doesn-t-support-this-action-error-445). My guess is it's `Selection.Copy` that's causing the error.

Comment: I have not tried this myself, but as a guess put this check as the first line of code: `If Selection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`. My thinking, based on @BigBen comment, is that nothing has been selected when it runs, so that the second time you run it, there is an active `Selection` object.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answers but if i dont have an active `Selection` the error is a differnt one: "This method or property is not available because no text is selected".

Comment: Why are you using the clipboard to do something as simple as turning the selected text into a hyperlink?

Comment: Because I need to turn a lot of links into hyperlinks and writing a makro saves me 4 clicks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the clipboard to create hyperlinks from selected text is entirely unnecessary.

```
Sub SelectedURLtoHyperlink()

    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=Selection.Text, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Selection.Text

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate your problem, so this is a bit of a shot in the dark. Try replacing

```
Set MyData = New DataObject
```

with

```
Set MyData = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
```

There are some issues with creating DataObject objects in new Windows.